# How to do a SQL with an IF condition on one column

Tags: .net, sql

I got a quick question about if this is possible within a SQL statement for an ASPX page.

Let's say there are three columns, `USER`, `Password`, and `permission`.

If within my `SELECT` statement I want to only select `USER` and `PASSWORD` only when `Permission` is `> 2`, and if it is less than 2 I only want to show `USER`.

Is this possible? Or will I have to do this within my presentation layer?

Comment: You're not storing passwords in plain text, do you ?

Comment: Yes it can be done with [`case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: For an assignment, so it is in plain text I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

Basic SQL..

```
select USER, CASE WHEN (Permission > 2) THEN PASSWORD ELSE null END
from YOURTABLE
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the permission level determines whether password should be retrieved as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?ppud=4) statement in your (T-)SQL query

```
SELECT [user], CASE 
                 WHEN Permission > 2 THEN [password] 
                 ELSE '' 
               END 
FROM [table]
```